# app.box .NET SDK returning empty collection of items

Tags: .net, sdk, jwt

I have followed the steps in .NET SDK documenation for JWT authenticated app, but keep getting empty items collection on **GetFolderItemsAsync** method.

I have configured it with Enterprise application access and authorized it...

Authentication seems ok, because I don't get an exception when creating the BoxJWTAuth object.

```
        var reader = new StreamReader(@"PathToJSONConfigFile");
        var json = reader
            .ReadToEnd();
        var config = BoxConfig
            .CreateFromJsonString(json);
        var sdk = new BoxJWTAuth(config);
        var token = sdk
            .AdminToken();

        var adminClient = sdk
            .AdminClient(token);

        var folders = await adminClient
            .FoldersManager
            .GetFolderItemsAsync("0", 500, fields: new string[] { BoxCollection.FieldEntries });
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out on my own.

Just in case somebody faces the same problem. I was trying to access folders with a automatically generated admin client. Apparently this type of client doesn't have authorization to get folder lists.

You have to get your enterprise users and instantiate a user client object with user id.

```
var boxUsers = await adminClient.UsersManager.GetEnterpriseUsersAsync();
        var user= boxUsers
            .Entries
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Login.Contains("user"));

        var cli = new BoxClient(config, auth, asUser: user.Id);
        try
        {
            var fold = await cli
            .FoldersManager
            .GetFolderItemsAsync("0", 500, fields: new string[] { BoxCollection.FieldEntries, BoxItem.FieldName, BoxItem.FieldSharedLink, BoxItem.FieldPathCollection });
```

Comment: Thank you - I was pulling my hair out over this!